# How to scrape data from table using CSS Selector and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

On this page, there is a series of tables I'm trying to get specific data from an unnamed table and unnamed cells. I used Copy Selector from the inspect elements in Chrome to find the CSS selector. When I'm asking Python to print that specific CSS Selector, i'm getting 'Nonetype' object is not callable

Specifically on this page, I am trying to get the number "198" to show up from the table in #general-info, article:nth-child(4), table:nth-child(2),

The CSS Selector path is :

```
"html body div#program-details section#general-info article.grid-50 table tbody tr td"
```

and this comes up using the Copy Selector

```
#general-info > article:nth-child(4) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)
```

Most of the code is accessing the site and bypassing the EULA. Skip to the bottom for the code i'm having problems with.

```
import mechanize  
import requests
import urllib2
import urllib
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]

sign_in = br.open('https://login.ama-assn.org/account/login')  #the login url

br.select_form(name = "go") #Alternatively you may use this instead of the above line if your form has name attribute available.

br["username"] = "wasabinoodlz" #the key "username" is the variable that takes the username/email value
br["password"] = "Bongshop10"    #the key "password" is the variable that takes the password value
logged_in = br.submit()   #submitting the login credentials
logincheck = logged_in.read()  #reading the page body that is redirected after successful login
#print (logincheck) #printing the body of the redirected url after login


# EULA agreement stuff
cont = br.open('https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/eula.do').read()
cont1 = br.open('https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/eulaSubmit.do').read()

# Begin request for page data
req = br.open('https://freida.ama-assn.org/Freida/user/programDetails.do?pgmNumber=1205712369').read()

#Da Soups!
soup = BeautifulSoup(req)
#print soup.prettify() # use this to read html.prettify()


for score in soup.select('#general-info > article:nth-child(4) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)'):
    print score.string
```

Comment: sorry, scratch that. Following that path, I can only find one `<td>` element nested

Comment: There's a table that gives "Total Program Size" in the first `article class="grid-50"`
Then there is another table in the second `article class="grid-50"`
Both have nested `<td>` tags

Comment: Alright I'll look into it

Comment: From what I can see, it looks like `table:nth-child(2)` is what's giving me problems. Try `table:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Have you managed to get any info/data from any of the tables? I have tried changing it to `table:nth-child(1)`, still getting not callable. In fact, i tried changing all the `nth-child(0)` just to see if i get anything

Comment: I couldn't from that specific URL. I can't physically test this at the moment, I'm working from Chrome DevTools. If you try appending `#general` at the end of your URL in `req = br.open()` that might yield some results

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `BeautifulSoup` using `html5lib` parser.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'html5lib')
```

`BeautifulSoup` only implements the `nth-of-type` pseudo selector.

```
data = soup.select(
          '#general-info > '
          'article:nth-of-type(4) > '
          'table:nth-of-type(2) > '
          'tbody > '
          'tr > '
          'td:nth-of-type(2)'
       )
```